# How to Open a file through python

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

I am very new to programming and the python language.

I know how to open a file in python, but the question is how can I open the file as a parameter of a function?

example:

```
function(parameter)
```

Here is how I have written out the code:

```
def function(file):
    with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
        contents = f.readlines()
    lines = []
    for line in f:
        lines.append(line)
    print(contents)
```

Comment: Side-note: The `readlines` method on files is redundant with files iterator behavior; in Python 3, `f.readlines()` is more verbose and no faster than (and in fact, in my tests, fractionally slower than) `list(f)`, and makes people write bad code by obscuring the iterator nature of files. In reality, you rarely want to do either `f.readlines()` or `list(f)`, because you usually want to iterate the file directly, either to process lines one at a time and discard them, or if you need a `list`, you still want some preprocessing (e.g. stripping newlines and/or blank lines) that as you iterate.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can easily pass the file object.

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f: #open the file
    contents = function(f) #put the lines to a variable.
```

and in your function, return the list of lines

```
def function(file):
    lines = []
    for line in f:
        lines.append(line)
    return lines
```

Another trick, python file objects actually have a method to read the lines of the file. Like this:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f: #open the file
    contents = f.readlines() #put the lines to a variable (list).
```

With the second method, `readlines` is like your function. You don't have to call it again.

**Update**
Here is how you should write your code:

First method:

```
def function(file):
    lines = []
    for line in f:
        lines.append(line)
    return lines 
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f: #open the file
    contents = function(f) #put the lines to a variable (list).
    print(contents)
```

Second one:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f: #open the file
    contents = f.readlines() #put the lines to a variable (list).
    print(contents)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Why is the example opening the file outside the function? Seems like the function was intended to receive a file name, open and read it, and return the contents as a `list`. Moving the `open` outside the function may make it more flexible (it can now be passed arbitrary file-like objects opened in different ways), but if the function is _supposed_ to open the file the same way, it just means all callers are doing the same work, when they could just pass the file name and keep the common file open code in the function.

Comment: I suppose it's possible the OP wanted to open the file outside the function and pass the file object, not the name, but that's really unclear from question and comments.

Answer (score 0):

Python allows to put multiple open() statements in a single with. You comma-separate them. Your code would then be:

```
def filter(txt, oldfile, newfile):
    '''\
    Read a list of names from a file line by line into an output file.
    If a line begins with a particular name, insert a string of text
    after the name before appending the line to the output file.
    '''

    with open(newfile, 'w') as outfile, open(oldfile, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            if line.startswith(txt):
                line = line[0:len(txt)] + ' - Truly a great person!\n'
            outfile.write(line)

# input the name you want to check against
text = input('Please enter the name of a great person: ')    
letsgo = filter(text,'Spanish', 'Spanish2')
```

And no, you don't gain anything by putting an explicit return at the end of your function. You can use return to exit early, but you had it at the end, and the function will exit without it. (Of course with functions that return a value, you use the return to specify the value to return.)

Answer (score 0):

```
def fun(file):
    contents = None

    with open(file, 'r') as fp:
        contents = fp.readlines()

    ## if you want to eliminate all blank lines uncomment the next line
    #contents = [line for line in ''.join(contents).splitlines() if line]

    return contents

print fun('test_file.txt')
```

or you can even modify this, such a way it takes file object as a function arguement as well

Comment: If you're going to do `splitlines` to remove newlines from lines and/or blank line elimination, you're better off either slurping as a single value and splitting, or processing line by line. Reading all the lines to a `list`, `join`ing the `list`, then `split`ing it up again is wasted work/memory (you're storing three copies of file data at once).

Comment: For a list of lines without newlines, you'd minimize time (if you have sufficient memory) with `contents = f.read().splitlines()` (which drops peak memory one copy of file data as a block and two copies of `list` of lines to one of each), or without blank lines (and still only two copies in memory at once), `contents = list(filter(None, f.read().splitlines()))`. To only have one copy as a `list`, no complete copies of the data in memory, process it line by line and both strip and filter as you go: `contents = [x for x in (x.rstrip('\r\n') for x in f) if x]`

Comment: Oh, and just for completeness, if you want to strip all trailing whitespace (not just newlines) and then strip blank lines, it can be optimized to `contents = list(filter(None, map(str.rstrip, f)))` which moves all the work to the C layer in CPython, at the expense of using `map` and `filter`, generally considered less Pythonic. Stripping only newlines is also possible this way, it's just uglier: `from operator import methodcaller`, `contents = list(filter(None, map(methodcaller('strip', '\r\n'), f)))`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a much simpler way of opening a file without defining your own function in Python 3.4:

```
var=open("A_blank_text_document_you_created","type_of_file")
var.write("what you want to write")
print (var.read()) #this outputs the file contents
var.close() #closing the file
```

Here are the types of files:

- `"r"`: just to read a file
- `"w"`: just to write a file
- `"r+"`: a special type which allows both reading and writing of the file

For more information see [this cheatsheet](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/cheatsheet/python-file-handling).

Answer (score -2):

```
def main():
       file=open("chirag.txt","r")
       for n in file:
              print (n.strip("t"))
       file.close()
if __name__== "__main__":
       main()


the other method is 


with open("chirag.txt","r") as f:
       for n in f:
              print(n)
```

Comment: This adds nothing to the existing answers, the formatting is terrible, and using explicit `close` instead of implicit close via `with` as your primary example is just encouraging bad practices.