# Speed up split and write out to file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm curious if there is a faster way to deal with big text files... 
I need to read quite a huge TXT file ( around 40MB :-/ ) which contains data separated by ";", remove the first 10 line as they are informative and not the main data, and then output just the first instance from each line so line[0] after split...

My current code does what it needs to, but it takes forever...

```
def remove_lines(input, output):
    lines = open(input).readlines()
    # clean the file before use
    open('output', 'w').close()
    # remove first lines and split by ; then output
    for l in lines[10:]:
        l = l.split(';')
        open(output, 'a').write(l[0] + "\n")
```

Its not like I need to do it often, maybe once a week so I can let it crunch as long as I want, but I'm curious if it can be speed up somehow...

Comment: Make sure you move `open(output, 'a')` _outside_ of the for loop. You're constantly reopening the file for no reason.

Comment: oh shoot, you are right, going to try it outside loop

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19508703/how-to-open-a-file-through-python and others. You should really be using `with` to handle your files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think 40MB is huge, you haven't seen huge ;) Either way, you don't need to read the whole file in memory, nor you need to split the whole line - it's sufficient just to skip the first `n` lines while reading and then get the line content up until the first semi-column, something like:

```
def remove_lines(input_file, output_file):
    with open(input_file, "r") as f_in, open(output_file, "a") as f_out:
        for i, line in enumerate(f_in):  # read the input line by line and enumerate it
            if i > 9:  # we're not interested in the first 10 lines
                sc_index = line.find(";")  # find the position of the first ; in line
                if sc_index != -1:  # found the first semi-column, get the content up to it
                    f_out.write(line[:sc_index] + "\n")  # write it to the output file
                else:
                    f_out.write(line)  # write the whole line as we couldn't find a ;
```

**UPDATE**: For the folks who think that `str.split("delim", 1)` is faster than finding the actual position and manually slicing, here's a simple test:

```
import timeit

def func_split(data):
    return data.split(";", 1)[0]

def func_find(data):
    index = data.find(";")
    if index != -1:
        return data[:index]
    return data


test1 = "A quick; brown; fox; with; semi; columns."
test2 = "A quick brown fox without semi columns."

assert func_split(test1) == func_find(test1)
assert func_split(test2) == func_find(test2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("func_split:", timeit.timeit("func_split(test1); func_split(test2)",
                                       "from __main__ import func_split, test1, test2",
                                       number=1000000))
    print("func_find: ", timeit.timeit("func_find(test1); func_find(test2)",
                                       "from __main__ import func_find, test1, test2",
                                      number=1000000))
```

And the results

```
CPython 2.7.11 x64 (1000000 loops):
('func_split:', 6.877725868989936)
('func_find: ', 6.228281754820999)

CPython 3.5.1 x64 (100000 loops):
func_split: 0.8343849130147841
func_find:  0.8080772353660183
```

YMMV, of course, but in general the latter will always be faster on CPython, and the speed difference will increase with each character added to the string as the `str.find()` doesn't need to pick up the whole string 'til the end nor needs to create a list to store it.

Comment: very nice solution as well.. in my case literally what was needed is to put open file outside the loop as @roganjosh suggested, it jumped from 30 min to 1.1s :D

Comment: I'm not sure where the comma comes into this? It looks delimited by `;` and split will still give back a single element list if there is no delimiter meaning that the 0th index should always be valid?

Comment: There is no need to manually search for a delimiter. You can just do `line.split(';', 1)`

Comment: @roganjosh - oops, i misread. But split will split the whole line without the need for it.

Comment: Aha, so you're short-circuiting? Fair enough. @VladoPortos you should still make not of the use of `with` in this answer, your other approach didn't close the file you were writing to (which would be handled by the context manager), and this is more pythonic in general.

Comment: This is how the function looks now:
def remove_lines(input, output):
    lines = open(input).readlines()
    open(output, 'w').close()
    file = open(output, 'a')
    for l in lines[10:]:
        l = l.split(';')
        file.write(l[0] + "\n")
    file.close()

This works super fast, and close the file after... should I still use "with" ? ( going to look into that one

Comment: @VladoPortos yes, you should always use `with`.

Comment: @EliKorvigo - there is, if the speed is what you're after and the OP was asking for speeding up his existing code.

Comment: @zwer using split with the second argument is most likely faster :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you shouldn't open your output file in a loop. That would make your OS very unhappy. Then, you only need to split up to the first instance of ";". Splitting by all instances is useless work. There is no need in calling `write` manually in your case, use the `print` function instead. and there sure is no need in storing all your data in RAM.

```
def remove_lines(input, output):
    with open(output, 'w') as out, open(input) as lines:
        # remove the first 10 lines
        for _ in range(10):
            next(lines)
        for l in map(str.strip, lines):
            print(l.split(";", 1)[0], file=out)
```

Comment: interesting, I didn't know you can chose not to care about the rest of the split stuff with (";", 1)

Answer (score 0):

As @zwer's solution, reading and processing in the loop allows I/O and cpu to be better utilized / interleaved ... And save memory.
This is more readable to my eyes:

```
def remove_lines(in_file, out_file):
    with open(in_file) as input, open(out_file, 'w') as output:
        for _ in range(10):
            input.readline()
        for line in input:
            output.write(line.split(';',1)[0] + '\n')
```

With a small amount of cpu mixed with I/O there is not much more optimizing that can be done.

Comment: it does what I need in 1.4sec, this on other hand does it in 0.9s

`def remove_lines(input, output):
    lines = open(input).readlines()
    open(output, 'w').close()
    file = open(output, 'a')
    for l in lines[10:]:
        l = l.split(';', 1)
        file.write(l[0] + "\n")
    file.close()`

But seems like I'm using bad practice not using "with" so I need to check upon that