# How to make a file open with Python program and do something with it?

Tags: python-3.x, file

How do I get a file to open in a python program and have it do something with the file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Open a file through python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19508703/how-to-open-a-file-through-python)

Comment: Read a file : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-do-i-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list and write in a file : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159900/correct-way-to-write-line-to-file

Answer (score 0):

Use this 
with operator will automaticly close file when you code in it executed

```
with open('your_file_name.extension', 'rw') as myfile:
        content = myfile.read()
        #do something with content
        myfile.write('some string') #add some content
```

Answer (score 0):

the best aproach is to use `with` statement.

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write('test')
```

But for more information, follow official documentation:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files