# How to open an image in Python 3.7?

Tags: python, import, canopy

How do I open an Image in Python 3.7?
I tried:

1.Import Image
Image.open("File_name.jpg")

Error received: ImportError: No module named 'Image'

2. Import cv2
   image = cv2.imread('backround.jpg')

Error received: ImportError: No module named 'cv2'

Please let me know of any other ways.

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to do. [Typical way of opening files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19508772/3701431) is via `with open('/path/to/image.png') as f:` . If you need to use it with a particular module, then you'll have to edit your question and explain exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Nether the `Image` module, nor `cv2` come with Python by default. You probably need to install the appropriate packages before your imports can work.

Comment: Okay I tried and I didnt get a picture, but I didnt get an error, here is what it did:%run "c:\users\my_user~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpgyzrfx.py"

Answer (score 5):

there are many libraries made for theses cases

so i'll explain **pillow**

first you need to install it 
you can use pip : **pip install Pillow**

or easy install : **easy_install Pillow**

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open(".../path_of_the_image/name.jpg")
im.show()
```

for more details you can visit the official documentation  [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/index.html)

Comment: when typing in pip install Pillow I got a an invalid syntax error

Comment: That needs to be entered on a command line, not inside Python.

Comment: This is a more stable link to the documentation: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/