# Python - Read file and save as Array

Tags: python, arrays, list

I am new here and I have a question for the start. I need to do some exercises for my school and there we use now Python as language. Python is a new language for me. So my problem is:

We need to open a text-file with a list of prices for a supermarket, like this:

```
{"rice": 2.10,
"orange":3.31,
"eggs":1.92,
"cheese":8.10,
"chicken":5.22}
```

How can I open this file and convert it into a array or something else, that i can work with it?
Furthermore I need this list as a hash array (named from `PowerShell`) to calculate in the next step with the products of the list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Open a file through python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19508703/how-to-open-a-file-through-python)

Comment: Maybe you want [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

Comment: [Do some research before asking.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: @ycao I think "json" is the missing piece here ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that the file you have is JSON format (I might be wrong). This can be very easily read into a `dict`.

I have created the file `test.dat` which contains the data. Then you simply do:

```
$ python3
Python 3.7.5 (default, Oct 22 2019, 10:35:10)
[Clang 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import json
>>> with open("test.dat") as f:
...     data = json.loads(f.read())
...     print(data)
...     print(data["rice"])
...
# data is now a dict which is a key=>value container
# you can see it like:
{'rice': 2.1, 'orange': 3.31, 'eggs': 1.92, 'cheese': 8.1, 'chicken': 5.22}
# you can also access individual keys like data["rice"] in this case
2.1
```

You can read more about JSON [here](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) and about python dictionaries (ie hashmaps) [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Comment: Thank you very much for the post! The missing piece was json and it works fine.