# Is there any way to write this type of permutations in a text file line by line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, permutation

I have this code:

```
import itertools
import string
variations = itertools.permutations(string.printable, 1)
for v in variations:
    text_file = open("Output.txt", "w")
    text_file.write(''.join(v))
    text_file.close()
```

But it doesn't work.When I run the .py file *Output.txt* is created but when I open it, I see an up arrow.I want to see an output like this:

```
1
2
3
4
...
```

Comment: Why are you opening and closing the file in each iteration? this will overwrite the file every time. just open and close once before/after the loop, or even better, use `with`

Comment: @DeepSpace I'm not familiar with python. can you explain more, please?

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19508703/how-to-open-a-file-through-python

Comment: Passing `1` as the value for `r` to `itertools.permutations` will result in just returning a list with a tuple for each char in `string.printable`, this doesn't seem very useful? You may as well just loop over `string.printable`

Comment: @Iain Shelvington It's just an example. I don't really want 1 as the value for r.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are opening and closing the file in every iteration with the `w` mode, which means the file gets truncated every iteration, which in turn means it will always contain only the last thing you wrote to it.

You may use the `a` mode which **a**ppends to the file.

A better approach will be to to open the file once before the loop, and close it once after the loop.

The best practice is to use the `with` context manager (google the term to find more info) which will handle the opening and closing of the file for you.

```
import itertools
import string

variations = itertools.permutations(string.printable, 1)

with open("Output.txt", "w") as f:
    for v in variations:
        f.write('{}\n'.format(''.join(v)))
```

Note that I added `\n` in the end of each line since I assumed you want each permutation in a separate line.

Comment: Is there any way to write each character in one line?

Comment: @ParsaFathollahi Yes, see the edited answer which adds `\n`

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
import itertools
import string
variations = itertools.permutations(string.printable, 1)

text_file = open("Output.txt", "w")
for v in variations:
    text_file.write(f"{v[0]}\n")

text_file.close()
```

As mentioned above there are better ways to do it. You are opening the file every iteration, only open it once. v is a tuple `('1',)` etc. so you need to index the first element.