# Not writing to external file in Python

Tags: python

```
points = str(points)
l = open("leaderboard.txt","a")
l.write(points)
```

I am attempting to write a value of 'points' to an external notepad file in python however the file comes out blank each time I run the program. 'points' previously was an integer value however I converted it to a string in order to store it in my file. Chances are I am missing something simple, but I cannot work it out, so any help would be much appreciated. Also, apologies for formatting errors, I am relatively new to this website.

Comment: Is it possible points was empty without you knowing. Can you print it after the str cast, just in case?

Comment: Also try adding `l.close()` at the end to force flushing, or use `with` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/19508772/13300960)

Answer (score 1):

Try printing points out to make sure it is not empty.

Then make sure you close the file with l.close()

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing the file. This is the main reason that it is not displaying. Use `l.close()` at the end of your code.
A better way is to use `with` expression so that file is closed automatically:

```
points = str(points)
with open('leaderboard.txt', 'a') as l:
    l.write(points)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because I/O operations are buffered in Python, you need to close the file to see the effect:

```py
points = str(points)
l = open("leaderboard.txt","a")
l.write(points)
l.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a best practice to use a context manager when using `open()`. Setting `l = open()` wasn't working for me either because it wasn't being closed. This will ensure the file is properly closed without having to worry about doing it manually:

```py
points = [(1, 1), (2, 2)]

points = str(points)
with open("leaderboard.txt","a") as file:
    file.write(points)
```

Output (leaderboard.txt):

```
[(1, 1), (2, 2)]
```