# How do you open text files in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
file = open('python-ai-info.txt', 'r')
words = file.read()
file.close()
```

Is this correct? Please help me fix it. I want to open file named python-ai-info.txt. I am currently getting error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sgcoder1337\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\rhyme ai.py", line 1, in <module>
    file = open('python-ai-info.txt', 'r')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'python-ai-info.txt'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Open a file through python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19508703/how-to-open-a-file-through-python)

Comment: Python cannot find the file. Make sure the file is in the same folder as this script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct, the error occurs because your directory is an invalid/nonexistent directory, try to use the complete directory like:

```
'C:/Users/Username/Desktop/Folder/filename.txt'
```

For opening file:

```
file = open(directory, flag)
```

Main flags (modes) are:

1. `"r"` for reading text, throws an exception if the file doesn't exist
2. `"rb"` for reading bytes, throws an exception if the file doesn't exist
3. `"w"` for writing text, doesn't throw an exception if the file doesn't exist, but creates it
4. `"wb"` for writing bytes, doesn't throw an exception if the file doesn't exist, but creates it
5. `"a"` for appending text, throws an exception if the file doesn't exist
6. `"ab"` for appending bytes, throws an exception if the file doesn't exist
7. `"x"` for creating files without opening, throws an exception if the file already exist

For reading files:

```
txt = file.read() # get the whole text
line = file.readline() # get a line
lines = file.readlines() # get a list of lines
```

For writing text:

```
file.write('txt')
```

For closing:

```
file.close()
```

For more detailed and complete info have a look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_handling.asp)

Comment: Other than providing some of the relevant documentation, this answer appears to be wrong, in that the problem isn't that the "directory is an invalid/nonexistent directory", but that the file simple doesn't exist in the script's working directory.